# $not operator in Mongo PHP query

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to write a query to Mongo DB with the following structure:

`not (condition1 or condition2)`

```
$query = ['$or' => [$condition1, $condition2]];
```

works correctly,

```
$query = ['$not' => ['$or' => [$condition1, $condition2]]];
```

is not working with error message `invalid operator: $or' in ...` in logs. What I'm doing wrong?

- PHP mongo extension Version => 1.4.5
- PHP => Version => 5.5.9
- MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator.

> `$nor` performs a logical `NOR` operation on an array of one or more query expression and selects the documents that fail all the query expressions in the array.

```
$query = ['$nor' => [$condition1, $condition2]];
```